# Docker swarm on AWS - swarm services cannot access internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dns, swarm

I've create a docker swarm (`Docker version 17.03.1-ce`) of one manager and 2 workers. All swarm nodes can "ping stackoverflow.com" but inside the swarm service containers I can "ping 8.8.8.8" and not "ping stackoverflow.com", they can not resolve the domain name.

on the manager I have in `/usr/sbin/dhclient-script`

```
search eu-central-1.compute.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

and on one of the containers I have in `/usr/sbin/dhclient-script`

```
search eu-central-1.compute.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Docker networks:

```
$ docker network ls

NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
ID                  bridge              bridge              local
ID                  docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
ID                  host                host                local
ID                  ingress             overlay             swarm
ID                  my_overlay          overlay             swarm
ID                  none                null                local
```

I start the docker service this way:

```
docker service create \
    --name myservice \
    --replicas 1 \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    --network my_overlay \
    --constraint 'node.role == manager' \
    --env COOKIE='SRV insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m maxlife 8h' \
    --env VIRTUAL_HOST='myservice' \
    --env SERVICE_PORTS='8080' \
myservice_image
```

AWS VPC and security groups are configured correctly I think, since ec2 instances can reach external domain names, and can be reached externally too.
Why can't myservice resolve for example `stackoverflow.com`?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is solved.

I habe to add `"dns": ["8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"]` to [`/etc/docker/daemon.json`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

I tried to do the same in /etc/default/docker, it didn't work, I guess that's the old way.

Comment: Good work~!!!Spent a few days on this connection issue and was working with the AWS team was thought some settings issue.

Comment: hey @kml I had exactly the same issue and did as you suggested and worked! Went crazy for a good amount of days regarding this. But it goes beyond me why adding google's DNS works, but adding the VPC (10.0.0.2) wouldn't work. Do you have an answer to that?

Comment: @user3353167 Did you only make this change on the EC2 instance running the Docker manager? Or did you have to update the daemon on all EC2 instances - IE: instances where the Docker nodes/workers were running?

Comment: every ec2 instance