# Docker swarm, cannot connect to aws RDS within container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, amazon-vpc

I have setup a docker swarm in my instance and I am having issues connecting to the database within a docker container. If I run `nslookup xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` I get

```
Server:         10.0.0.2
Address:        10.0.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: xxx.x.x.xx
```

But as soon as I ssh into a docker container and repeat the same command, I get:

```
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11:53

** server can't find xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com: SERVFAIL
```

Both RDS and EC2 are part of the same VPC, the RDS instance is not public
What could be the potential issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the DNS configuration of the docker container. Container cannot get the DNS configuration while running.

Test:

```
docker run -it --dns=10.0.0.2 <ImageName:tag> bash 
e.g. docker run -it --dns=10.0.0.2 ubuntu:22.04 bash 
apt update
apt install dnsutils
nslookup xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

To make it persistent (For Linux instances):

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
#copy followings:
{
  "dns": [ "10.0.0.2" ],
}
sudo systemctl restart docker  # restart docker service, or restart ec2 instance
```

For Win instances:

```
create C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json
#copy followings:
{
   "dns": [ "10.0.0.2" ],
}
Restart-Service -Name docker  # restart docker service
```

**EDIT:**

If it has invalid DNS, then your container won't be able to resolve hostnames. Adding Google public DNS may solve the issue.

These are Google DNS Servers: https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062

Test:

```
docker run -it --dns=8.8.8.8 ubuntu:22.04 bash 
apt update
apt install dnsutils
nslookup xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

To make it persistent (For Linux instances):

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
#copy followings:
{
  "dns": [ "10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ],
}
sudo systemctl restart docker  # restart docker service, or restart ec2 instance
```

Comment: thanks for the tip but unfortunately it did not work :/

Comment: Did u try to add 'network_mode: "host"' to your service or use an overlay network?

Comment: yes so I'm already using an overlay network. I just tried to add network_mode but I get: Ignoring unsupported options

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031835/docker-swarm-on-aws-swarm-services-cannot-access-internet but it goes beyond me why this works

Comment: Does it solve? : "dns": ["8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"] to /etc/docker/daemon.json, according to it, I'll add it

Comment: It does solve but I don't understand why and I would like to

Comment: The reason may be intermittent DNS resolution or responses. "For example, you configure the rotate option in resolv.conf to load balance DNS queries between the Amazon DNS server and the public Google resolver server (8.8.8.8)", written in AWS documentation, Ref:  https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-fix-dns-resolution-private-zone